# Time complexity of determining if a string is a subset of another string

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-complexity

What is the Big-O of determining if a string is a subset of another string? In another word, does a string contain all characters of another string?

For example, `A = 'string'` `B = 'gti'`, `B` is a subset of `A`.

My approach is to use all the characters of `A` to create a Map. Then, iterate `B` to cross-check with the Map. The Big-O of this method is `O(m + n)`. Is this the best worst-case time complexity I can get?

Comment: What are `m` and `n`?

Comment: Length of array `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you can solve the problem without (in the worst case) at least inspecting every character of each string, you can't do better than O(m+n) (assuming m & n are the 2 string lengths).